# Invalid operation exception blocks the whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config

i have a page with asp repeater having around 1000 rows, for some operations when i use post it runs into exception and after that whole page goes nonfunctional.

it says "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

and shows the below stack trace

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2428582
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +58
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +159

[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +217
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +104
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +9117999
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +97
   System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +69
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +135
</pre></code>
```

i already have set `MaxHttpCollectionkeys` to 50,000 
iam using WCF, i dont understand why is this happening, can some one help??, Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post all the relevant code? I'm not sure anyone could help with the object current state if we can't see what object it is!?

Comment: add some screenshot along with code. @Amarnath

Comment: This was Happening due to exxessive number of server controls, Viewstate was growing more than allowed size